# Can I bind silverlight controls to DynamicObject.Properties?

Tags: silverlight, binding, dynamic

I have a DynamicObject class that is binded to some controls in silverlight xaml.

```
class Localizer
{
    public Strings Strings { get; set; }
}

public class Strings : DynamicObject
{
    Dictionary<string, string> values;

    public Strings(Dictionary<string, string> values)
    {
        this.values = values;
    }

    public override bool TryGetMember(GetMemberBinder binder, out object result)
    {
        string value;
        bool success = values.TryGetValue(binder.Name, out value);
        result = value;
        return success;
    }
}
```

and bind some controls to this like this:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Strings.User, Source={StaticResource Localizer}}"/>
```

When I run the application I get this error in VS output:

System.Windows.Data Error: BindingExpression path error: 'Login' property not found on '....Localization.StringsResource' '....Localization.StringsResource' (HashCode=10857028). BindingExpression: Path='Strings.Login' DataItem='....Localization.Localizer' (HashCode=30604389); target element is 'System.Windows.Controls.Button' (Name='btnLogin'); target property is 'Content' (type 'System.Object').

but when read property in code like this:

```
string UserName = localizer.Strings.Login;
```

It work correctly, is it possible to bind controls to DynamicObject in xaml?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately this is a bug in silverlight,   :(
[Databinding to Dynamic Objects is Broken](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/522119/databinding-to-dynamic-objects-is-broken#)

Answer (score 0):

In Silverlight 4, you can't data bind properties, but you can data bind indexers.  Since I assume you aren't supporting live data changes in that your Strings object, as it doesn't support `INotifiyPropertyChanged` you could just return the dictionary and use the indexer binding syntax.

But if you did need to support INotifiyPropertyChanged, silverlight has syntax for notifying changes of specific indexer values `new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Item["+key+"]")` that you could use in the Strings object.

Silverlight 5 may have a easy [workaround](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/silverlight_sdk/archive/2011/04/26/binding-to-dynamic-properties-with-icustomtypeprovider-silverlight-5-beta.aspx), or a difficult one, it's hard to say at this point.